# How do I update the title and data of a matplotlib bar chart animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to create a horizontal bar chart where the title and data change during each frame. The issue I am running into is that if I use `blit=True`, the data updates but not the title. When I use `blit=False` the title changes but not the data (it only increases).

I have read through dozens of answers and tried everything including ***set_title*** and ***set_text*** but I am at a total loss. Thank you for your help.

```
%matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 
import csv

people = ('','Jim', 'Dan')
plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))

ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis() 
ax.set_xlabel('Skill')
titleList=['Basketball','Hockey']
df=[[0,5,7],[0,4,9]]
title = ax.text(0.5,0.95, "Test", bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")
def animate(i):
       # Example data
    while i<2:
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_yticklabels(people)
        ax.set_xlabel(titleList[i])
        performance=df[i]
        title.set_text(str(titleList[i]))
        line= ax.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center',
                color='blue', ecolor='None')
        return line

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, frames=5, blit=True
                            ,interval=2000,repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You call a `FuncAnimation()` with `frames=5`, `animate(i)` will thus try to set label and titel via `titleList[i]` which however only has 2 entries. Especially with `blit=True`, this will throw errors.
2. Your `animate()` functions returns `line`; if we `print(line)`, we find it is rather a `<BarContainer object of 3 artists>` than a line, i.e. the three rectangles of `barh()`. You should rather store the `barh()` in `rects` and then `return [rect for rect in rects]`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377418/bar-graph-in-subplot2grid)

**Complete Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl ## uncomment this if you are running this on a Mac
mpl.use('TkAgg')         ## and want to use blit=True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 
import csv

people = ('','Jim', 'Dan')
plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))

ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis() 
ax.set_xlabel('Skill')
titleList=['Basketball','Hockey']
df=[[0,5,7],[0,4,9]]
def animate(i):
   # Example data
    while i<2:
        ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
        ax.set_yticklabels(people)
        ax.set_xlabel(titleList[i])
        performance=df[i]

        title = ax.text(0.5,0.95,str(titleList[i]), bbox={'facecolor':'w', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")

        rects = ax.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center',
                color='blue', ecolor='None')
        return [rect for rect in rects] + [title]


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, frames=2, blit=True
                            ,interval=2000,repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  

1. You're right. I had it as 5 because that's the real size but I took away the titles in order to have a more compact example. I have changed this.                                                                                                                   

2. I am not sure how to apply this to my example. Since set_height and set_width don't exist in **barh**, what would I assign as **rect**. 

Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Jimmy I've updated my answer with the complete code.

Comment: Thank you again. The only issue is that because you're using **blit=False** the rectangles do not get updated when the number (width) is lower than in the previous frame, which is the same issue I already had before.

Comment: Set `blit=True` then?

Comment: Then the title doesn't change. This was the original dilemma. Need to change both the rectangles and the title.

Comment: Ooops, I totally forgot about that, I am sorry. Updated my answer again, now the `title=ax.text()` line is *inside* the animate function, and is returned as an iterable artist list, i.e. `[title]`

Comment: Thank you!! Accepted. Only explanation I am curious about is how does the **AnimationFunc** know what the data vs what the title is. Thank you again!!

Comment: @Jimmy also note that you could use `for i in range(len(rects)):` to iterate over the individual bars and then run `rects[i].set_width()` to set the width, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143866/565489)